# Correct way to inferring parameter property with dynamic to generalize function?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have a dozen different functions that takes a different objects each and do some work with the parameter object's id

```
public void MyFunctionForTypeA(TypeA value)
{
   DoSomething(value.Id);
}

public void MyFunctionForTypeB(TypeB value)
{
   DoSomething(value.Id);
}
...
```

assuming that every objects has an Id property, is there a way to generalize the functions?

I tried this, but I think/hope there's a better way

```
public void MyFunctionForEveryType(object value)
{
   dynamic myValue = value;
   DoSomething(myValue.Id);
}
```

(do I realy have to use dynamics in the first place? is there any reflection trick to achieve this?)

and no, sadly all parameters objects don't have a common interface or a base class of any kind :(

Comment: You could always use GetType() to find out the type of the object being passed and use a switch statement, but if every object has an Id property, I don't see anything wrong with what you have above, using dynamic.

Comment: AFAIK, If you don't have a common interface / base with the Id property, It's either dynamic or reflection unfortunately.

Comment: You could try via reflection `obj.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(obj)`.

Comment: Assuming you cannot change the types signatures, the best strongly typed, OOP way of doing this is exactly what you have done already: **using overloads**.  I know you might have a lot of code but its not inefficient or bad code, its necessary to preserve the strongly typed integrity of your app. I would avoid `dynamic` always.

Comment: "is there any reflection trick to achieve this?" Sure, but it gets even uglyier then the code you already have (`dynamic` in fact also relies on reflection). I can´t see anything whrong in your code despite the fact of the bad design of your classes.

Comment: I inherited this code... same old story :)

Comment: Seems not a problem to add interface to those types? Just a dozen, and should not break anything.